Why is Acoustic Impedance Proportional to the Speed of Sound if It Measures Difficulty of Wave Propagation?
I am studying Advanced Level Physics and I am confused about the following entry in my notes:

If acoustic impedance is a "measure of how difficult it is for an acoustic wave to travel through the medium", then why is the acoustic impedance proportional the speed of sound in the medium? Surely if a higher impedance means that it is more difficult for an acoustic wave to travel through that medium than a medium of lower impedance, then the speed of sound (c) in the higher impedance medium would be lower, not greater (assuming equal density)?

IMHO, that is not the best way to describe impedance. Here is another view:
In an electrical system, the characteristic impedance of a transmission line is the ratio of voltage to current- that is, how many volts are required to produce a fixed amount of current flow- and has units of ohms.
Now, you can say that a high impedance circuit is one in which signals are propagated by high voltages that produce tiny currents, and a low impedance circuit is one in which signals are propagated by small voltages which produce large currents. In neither case is it particularly "difficult" to propagate a signal; the difficulties arise when the impedance of a source that is driving signals down a line is different from the impedance of the line. If this is so, then most of the applied signal bounces off the junction between the source and the line and is reflected back into the source. Very little of the signal makes it into the line in this case, and we say that the source finds it difficult to drive the line.
The same can be said about acoustic systems. If we want a source to radiate sound in air without difficulty, we note that air is very springy and has very low density- so the sound source has to be equally springy and equally dense.
If we want to drive sound into a steel beam- which is extremely nonspringy and very dense- without difficulty, then the source has to be dense and stiff as steel.
So... a piezo transducer, which is dense and stiff, will easily drive sound down the length of a steel beam- but when presented with air and not steel, the transducer is poorly coupled to the medium and will not radiate well.
